# Retrofit returns JSON response with null values but postman returns correct JSON

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I'm fetching product types from api using retrofit and gson as the default converter. Problem is the JSON response is not same as the expected value. One field is always null. The field is named banner which is an image url.

The model class looks like this:

```
public class ProductType {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private Date createdAt;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("banner")
    @Expose
    private String banner;

   //getter and setters
```

The expected results is:

```
  {
      "id": "c9f32ed3-877a-4140-97c4-b0982",
      "created_at": "2018-09-20T18:49:59.044682+03:00",
      "name": "Events",
      "description": "",
      "banner": "https://my-server-url/types/banners/c9f32ed3-877a-4140-97c4-b0982/98673e1e-d1c0-9d2e165159dc.jpg"
  }
```

Retrofit returns the following response:

```
 {
     "id": "c9f32ed3-877a-4140-97c4-b0982",
     "created_at": "2018-11-06T10:46:48.552284+03:00",
     "name": "Events",
     "description": "",
     "banner": null
 }
```

Is there anything wrong with with the image Url since other fields are parsed well?

I have tried to use moshi converter but it did not work. Any ideas would help. Thanks

Comment: Is this the raw json from Postman?

Comment: @dharms Yes it i. Even on the browser, the get request returns the same JSON as postman

Comment: at first sight, this should work. Where are you getting the retrofit json from? The android logs, a proxy, just inspect the java model and assuming the json is null? I'd also check the headers automatically sent by postman. Sometimes servers cannot cope without some of these headers and send unexpected results when they're missing. Try and add them to the call if that's the case and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @cheruiyot I am facing the same issue. How did you solve that?